# Best data structure for a effecient insertion, deletion and occasional traversal

Tags: c++, data-structures

So, I'm trying to make a personal project and I need to know what data structure can I use which enables me to allow for fast insertions and deletions in any order. On top of it, it'd be for best if I can manage data internally . I tried a hash set, but feedback from a senior was that it isn't the best choice. So I want to know what can I use?

some additional context: performance is paramount irrespective of amount if data in structure. Insertions and removals are highly frequent and in random order

Comment: I'd ask the senior what their recommendation is. With the vague details you've given it sounds like a `std::unordered_set` would be fine.

Comment: unordered set is exactly what I used. I was given advice to look at something like linked list since I might need to maintain index. I do have the restriction that I need  frequent insertions and removals

Comment: *"I'm trying to make a personal project for my git repo"* -- is this relevant to the question or just fluff to make your question look longer? It might be better to start with something more like "I am designing a data structure that needs to [etc.]"

Comment: the note was just to make sure that no one thinks this is an academic assignment. I left university long back and am currently working on fluffing up my git repo alongside my job

Comment: If you could provide some sample usage information about what you're storing and how you need to put it into the structure and how you need to get it back out of the structure, that might help us narrow it down.

Comment: `std::unordered_set`, is typically implemented as a hash table with `O(1)` insertion time, deletion time, and lookup time. It has an iterator. Other than the overhead of the class itself, it's really hard to beat.  But you aren't giving enough details about what you are really trying to do.

Comment: does it slow down with large number of data points and frequent insertions/deletions? I want to know the reason behind my seniors feedback, but I doubt he'll answer which is why I am asking here

Comment: A linked list is only good if you already have a pointer to the node you want to delete or the node at the place where you want to insert.  If you don't you will need to find the node/spot by traversing - and that would be slow.  unordered_set is just as fast but you don't have any control over the order of the items so if you do need an index it doesn't work for you.  Is he right that you need to be in control of the order of the items?

Comment: I don't need complete control over order of items, but I do need loose control (IDK about the best term here) since my data can't be added back once removed. Plus I need to iterate over them to make sure that I get the data I need

Comment: @krabby_patty If the "personal project" note is just to provide some additional context, then it would be better placed as more of a footnote than a lead-in.

Answer (score -1):

LinkedList is your best choice. In std lib, std::list is its implemention.

> Lists are sequence containers that allow constant time insert and erase operations anywhere within the sequence, and iteration in both directions.

As long as you know the list node address and position which is inserted after.

Just increment your iterator before inserting your value:

```
if (someIterator != someList.end()) {
    someIterator++;
}
someList.insert(someIterator, someValue);
```

But there is no way to have O(1) erasure from std::list.Unless you know the index or iterator of deleted element.

You may want to consider using an intrusive list, where list nodes are directly imbedded into the structures, like you have already done.

you can use boost::intrusive or roll your own.

## Own impletion

### define Node

```
/* Node of a doubly linked list */
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next; // Pointer to next node in DLL
    struct Node* prev; // Pointer to previous node in DLL
};
```

Now you can erase or insert by Node* pointer.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'll try doing this